# Show Laravel SQL from migation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way to show the actual SQL that Laravel-4 will run against a database given a migration?

I would like to see how it will behave before I actually commit it to a database.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This does the trick:

> php artisan migrate --pretend

Comment: Exceptionally useful for debugging valid PHP that generates invalid SQL. In my case, an the (optional) parameter for a decimal was not being specified $table->decimal(10,2) had a  period  instead of a comma.